# What use cases are there for defining a new root class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, theory

We know that in Objective-C there are two main root classes:  `NSObject` and `NSProxy`.  There are other roots (mainly for private and legacy purposes) like `Object`, and `NSLeafProxy`.

Defining a new root is fairly trivial:

```
@interface DDRoot <NSObject>

@end

@implementation DDRoot

//implement the methods required by <NSObject>

@end
```

My question is: why would you ever want to define a new root class?  Is there some use-case where it's necessary?

Comment: I could have sworn I knew this question was coming! :)

Comment: @Jacob that little exchange earlier got me thinking, and I couldn't come up with a reasonable answer. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there should be no reason for creating your own root class, because short of implementing all of the `NSObject` protocol methods yourself, you're going to be missing out on a lot of functionality, and going to be making a lot of calls to the Objective-C runtime that should essentially be done for you.

Unless you really had to implement the protocol differently from the default (`NSProxy` is a special case that *does* have to), you shouldn't need to make your own root class. I mean, you'd have to be writing a class that cannot *fundamentally* be represented by `NSObject` and the protocol as implemented by Apple, and in that case, why are you even writing it in Objective-C?

That's what I think. Maybe someone can come up for a creative use for it.

(People researching the topic should go look at the [NSObject Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSObject Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject), ['Core Competencies: Root Class' document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/RootClass.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH46), and the 'Root Class' section of the [Fundamentals Guide: Cocoa Objects document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW35).)

Comment: I think your point about wanting fundamentally different behavior is the defining reason.  Most of the methods in `<NSObject>` seem related to memory management, so you'd probably want to use a new root class if you wanted to do something absurdly bizarre with  that.

Comment: I can think of one possible use, but there are probably better ways to do it, and there isn't really any need for it. You could define a new framework that obfuscates the calls and uses it's own runtime to decode the protected parts of the program. But again, WHY?

Answer (score 12):

There are two primary reasons to create a new root class; proxying & a new object model.

When proxying, it can be useful to implement a new root class such that you can basically handle any and all of the class/object's behaviors in a custom fashion.  See NSProxy.

The Objective-C runtime is flexible enough that you can support a new object model quite easily (where **easily** discounts the inherent complexity of creating such a beast in the first place).   Actually, many of the behaviors that are considered inherent to the runtime -- KVC, KVO, etc.. -- are implemented as a part of the `NSObject` class itself.

I know of at least one company that -- as of about 8 years ago, at least -- had implemented their own object model as a part of building their ~500k LOC financial analysis engine.

The key, though, is that if you go this route, you *don't* try to make your classes interact with Foundation/CF/AppKit/UIKit, etc.  If you need **that**, just subclass NSObject already!

It is interesting to note that `NSManagedObject` is effectively a root class in that it does some pretty seriously custom stuff, but it is a subclass of `NSObject` so subclasses of `NSManagedObject` are inter-operable with the rest of the system.

Answer (score 5):

Objective-C and Cocoa are separate things, and in principle it’s possible to define entirely new application frameworks that don’t use Foundation. The financial analysis people bbum mentioned are a practical example, and I believe they’re still around.

Another use is to make a proxy that’s more minimal than `NSProxy`, as Mike Ash does [here](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-02-26-futures.html).

Oh, and the private `NSInvocationBuilder` is a root class, presumably for the same reasons as Mike’s proxy. Capturing invocations for later use is something one might want to recreate.

Comment: I recently found myself implementing a root class for another reason: I wanted NSZombie-style behaviour for objects that used custom memory management (don't ask). To ensure that _all_ messages would result in a zombie crash, the base zombie class was a root class with no methods except -forwardingTargetForSelector:.

Answer (score 1):

Companies like the OmniGroup have defined a version of NSObject to use as their own base class for everything.

It's essentially a subclass of NSObject with some debug stuff.  Other than that, it's usually a terrible idea to fight the framework.

Find Omni's code here:
https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup

Comment: Actually, `OBObject` is not a root class, but a regular subclass of `NSObject` that they personally use as the basis for their framework. It's not strictly root.

Comment: Did you read my post?  "It's essentially a subclass of NSObject with some debug stuff..."

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I read 'root class,' instead of subclass. Too hasty on the reading there... ;)

Comment: I do it all the time.  No worries!